# How to aggregate time-series data over specific ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, aggregate

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this, whereby each row represents data collected on a different day (days 1 -> 5) for each participant (long form).

```
ID    Heart_Rate
1         89
1         98
1         99 
1         73 
1         54
...
24        88
24        90
24        79
24        92
24        97
```

How can I aggregate the data over the first 3 days for each participant such that I create a new data frame with 1 row for each patient whereby the data represents the mean heart rate over 72 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the `index` of dataframe to `ID` then `group` the dataframe on `level=0` and aggregate using `head` to select first three rows for each user `ID` then take `mean` on `level=0` to get the average heart rate over the first `72` hours:

```
out = df.set_index('ID').groupby(level=0).head(3).mean(level=0)
```

Alternate approach which is more **efficient** but applicable **only if there are always equal number of rows present** corresponding to each user `ID` and dataframe is **sorted** on `ID` column:

```
n_days = 5 # Number of rows present for each user ID
n_days_to_avg = 3 # First n rows/days to average

m = np.isin(np.r_[:len(df)] % n_days, np.r_[:n_days_to_avg])
out = df[m].groupby('ID').mean()
```

---

```
>>> out

    Heart_Rate
ID            
1    95.333333
24   85.666667
```

Comment: What is the  purpose of the "[0, 1, 2]" in the alternative method?

Comment: @ummendial  We are creating a boolean mask using `np.isin` ..so `[0, 1, 2]` allows us to create a boolean mask in such a way that we could be able to select only the first three rows for each `ID`. Again note that this alternate method is only applicable if there are always five rows present in the dataframe for each user id and dataframe is sorted on userid.

Comment: Yeah that is the case I have but I'm just wondering how to adapt this to  a larger dataset where there are say 50 rows for each participant and I am interested in aggregating over the first 25?

Comment: @ummendial Give me 10 mins I will update the answer for general case...just attending a call.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it :) - Could you also possibly demonstrate how to do this in for loop (in case there are several variables that I wanted to do this across)?